# How to have a count by week depending on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for something like that.

```
StartOfWeek EndOfWeek   WeekNumber  order_opened    order_send  order_closed
2019-01-01  2019-01-06  2019W01         
2019-01-07  2019-01-13  2019W02         
2019-01-14  2019-01-20  2019W03         
2019-01-21  2019-01-27  2019W04         
2019-01-28  2019-02-03  2019W05
```

I have a table with 4 column  , order_id , opening_date, sending_date and closing_date, i can also create a date table.
I think i have to use 'with',
But i can't find a solution that is working,
Any help would be great .

Regards
Antoine

Comment: Please provide sample data and corresponding results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to unpivot and aggregate.  I would recommend:

```
select c.weeknumber, sum(is_open), sum(is_send), sum(is_close)
from t cross apply
     (values (opening_date, 1, 0, 0),
             (sending_date, 0, 1, 0),
             (closing_date, 0, 0, 1)
     ) v(date, is_open, is_send, is_close) join
     calendar c
     on v.date = c.date
group by c.weeknumber;
```

I doubt the first two columns are important for the question.  Without seeing the calendar table or a definition of "week" it is hard to specify the best way to determine them.